# Android find document in image

Tags: android, image, opencv, vuforia

I'm fairly familiar with android application developpement and have created quite a few apps within Android-Studios. Now I'd like to do an app wich can detect a A4 paper in an image and read it's content. Can you name me a couple of libraries/API's? I've checked out OpenCV and Vuforia, but couldn't find something with this particular problem.
Thanks alot!

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The best (free) possibility for OCR (Optical Character Recognition) would be Tesseract Engine.
Please note however, that you'll need some background in image processing to get reasonable results.
There are libraries that do the preprocessing for you, but most of them are commercial projects.